# Entity Framework Attach Exception caused by automatic recursive attaching of referenced entities

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have two detached entities that have been eagerly loaded with multiple other entities. (1 to n relation).

The eagerly loaded entities that reference the detached entity (stored in an ICollection navigation property) can exist in both of the two detached entities.

When I want to attach both detached entities I get an Exception because the eagerly loaded entities are already attached.

This is an exemplary code with comments to explain the problem:

```
public ProvokeAttachException()
{
    //s1 and s2 share some of their samples
    sample_set s1 = GetSampleSet(1);
    sample_set s2 = GetSampleSet(2);

    //Do some stuff

    //Attaching the sample_sets again
    using(StationContext context = new StationContext())
    {
        // Fine
        context.sample_set.Attach(s1);

        //Throws Exception because some of the included samples in sample_set
        //have been attached automatically with s1
        context.sample_set.Attach(s2); 
    }

}

public sample_set GetSampleSet(int setId)
{
    //Eager Loading all samples that reference sample_set (1 to n relation)
    using (StationContext context = new StationContext())
    {
        return context.sample_set.Include("sample").FirstOrDefault(s => s.id = setId);
    }
}
```

How can I attach both entities without an exception?

Comment: Could you provide more information about your data modeling. You might need to do some refactor in it. If a object is already attached, you can't attached it again.

Comment: @PedroSouki I know that I can't attach an entity again. I have a new context and attaching s1 and s2 is the first thing that I do, so they can't be attached already. It is because of the 'sample'-entities that are eagerly loaded and some of them are shared by s1 and s2. Attach is attaching all referenced entities that are included in the navigation properties recursively and automatically. I don't know how I can avoid the exception and that all the entities included in s1 and s2 get attached

Comment: @FelixKeil I'm challenged with similar requirement. I'm just wondering if you still remember how you solved this challenge.. I would highly appreciate your suggestion.

Comment: @user1814131 unfortunately I don't remember what our workaround was and I don't have access to the code base anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the attaching thing, use `Add` instead.

When you do the `context.sample_set.Attach(s1);`, what it really does is create the instance of all related objects in the new context and then add them to the sample_set, that why it works.

When you try to `context.sample_set.Attach(s2);`, it tries to create again all shared `samples`, that is why it throws the exception.

So my suggestion to you is :

```
context.sample_set.Add(s1);
context.sample_set.Add(s2);
context.SaveChanges();
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! But Add is for adding/inserting new entries into the database. s1 & s2 are existing in database and are only detached from the context and need to be attached again. All the shared samples and non shared samples are already existing in the database. So I cleary need an Attach not an Add

Comment: I'm not understanding why you need to detach the entities. If you want just edit retrieve the data make the changes set the  `context.Entry(obj).State = EntityState.Modified;`  and SaveChanges

Comment: The general reason to use Attach is that the entities don't have to be retrieved again, but can be used like they were retrieved from db and that no database transaction is needed. E.g. NavigationProperties are not working if you wire up some attached entities with detached entities